# Unexpected issue with max function in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion, max

I have this function that removes the maximum value of a list and it seems to work, and when I keep adding numbers it works until I add a new high number. Then it will still remove only the old max number. But when I start a new list it will work again. Can anyone explain what is going on, and what I am doing wrong?

```
    removeMax :: [Int] -> [Int]
    removeMax [] = []
    removeMax [x] = [] 
    removeMax (x:y:xs)
        | x > y = (y:xs)
        | otherwise = x : removeMax (y:xs)
```

And here is the outputs of several tests I made:

```
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6]
    [1,3,2,6]
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6,8]
    [1,3,2,6,8]
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6,8,7]
    [1,3,2,6,8,7]
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    [1,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    [1,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    *Main> removeMax [1,9,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    [1,3,2,6,8,7,14]
    *Main> removeMax [1,3,14,5]
    [1,3,5]
    *Main> removeMax[1,3,8,9]
    [1,3,8]
    *Main> removeMax [1,2,3,67,87,12]
    [1,2,3,67,12]
    *Main> removeMax [1,2,3,67,87,12,88]
    [1,2,3,67,12,88]
```

As you can see it works when you keep doing it on new lists and when you use an old list and only add smaller numbers.

Comment: Well your function will remove values given the **next value** is smaller than that value. So `9` is removed in your first example.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what about the issue that I am posting about?

Comment: Your function does not remove the maximum. It removes the first value that is followed by a smaller one -- which may or may not be the maximum. You need to scan the list twice: one to find the maximum, and another one to remove it. Doing in one pass only seems to be more tricky (and possibly require subtle techniques like tying the knot, which you should disregard for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing weird about the way your function behaves - you defined it to remove **the first number that is larger than its successor**.

To really remove the maximum from a given list, the easiest approach is to:

- find the maximum by scanning the whole list
- remove it

An implementation of this approach is pretty straightforward using two helper functions:

```
  findMax: [Int] -> Int
  removeElement: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
```

However, you should also consider edge cases:

- what happens if the maximum occurs more than once? I.e. should `removeMax [1, 3, 2, 3]` return `[1,2,3]`, `[1,2]` or `[1,3,2`] ?
- does your new implementation handle the empty list correctly? (your current one does)

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to say that I can use two methods. If there is a way to do one method using another method then I wouldn't even know where to start with that, the professor didn't explain that. But thank you and I see now what I did wrong. Oh well, back to the drawing board.